# Batch file to commit changes to Embedded XP and then restart pc

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, embedded

I would like to create a batch file to run a cmd command to commit changes to a windows embedded pc from a USB drive and restart the PC to make the changes active.

The cmd line I use is:

```
ewfmgr -commit c:
```

But I need to open the cmd prompt and run the command then once it has run, restart the PC

This is what worked

```
@echo OFF
:reboot
c:\windows\system32\ewfmgr.exe C: -commit
echo Rebooting...Please Wait
c:\windows\system32\xpepm.exe -restart
pause
```

Comment: It is not clear for me. If you create a file.bat and put your command into it you can simply launch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutdown /?` could give some hints. Then your batch file might look as follows:

```
ewfmgr -commit c:
shutdown /r
```

To ensure batch wait until `ewfmgr` command ends, use

```
start "" /W ewfmgr -commit c:
shutdown /r
```

With the `/W` or `/WAIT` switch, the `start` command will start application and wait for it to terminate. [More info on `start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

To give a some kind of wait after the commit command so that it can run and finish its task, e.g. for a delay of 30 seconds:

- add `timeout /T 30 /nobreak>nul` line before `shutdown /r`, and/or
- use `shutdown` with `/t xxx` switch (this sets the time-out period
  before shutdown to `xxx` seconds), i.e. `shutdown /r /t 30`

A workaround if  `timeout` command is not recognized: `PING -n 31 127.0.0.1>nul`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the above runs the Commit command but does not restart the computer, do I need some kind of wait after the commit command so that it can run and finish before the restart?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file with the .bat extension. Open it in your preferred text editor and enter the commands you want to be run, and save the file. The commands that JosefZ wrote would probably do the job perfectly.